# The youtube video is not loading in the my local webpage

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I have taken the following iframe code for the youtube video from the youtube itself.

```
<iframe width=”560? height=”315? src=”http://www.youtube.com/embed/V3oJR5IAMxM” frameborder=”0? allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But when i try to embed this video on simple web-page inside a div element. I can see the you-tube player in the web page.But the video is not loading in my webpage. But the same video is playing for me in youtube.

Can someone tell what might be the problem,..

Is the problem with a code or with the browser, i am using mozilla 13.

Comment: What are these question marks ? Try replacing them with quotes.

Comment: Yeah i just fixed the question marks, this also works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HiTbmBizz,

Try this instead,

`<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/V3oJR5IAMxM?feature=player_embedded" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Worked for me in HTMLSandbox if you want to test.

Let me know how it goes.