# How to embed some YouTube videos on non-public domain pages?

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api, embed

I am currently writing an audioplayer with which YouTube videos can be played & controlled with hotkeys. However, I am having an issue: Videos that should be available for embedding get a "Not available" error for some reason.

An example of the embedding code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/d6QE4EJrIFc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When I paste this into any random .html file and open it in my browser, I get the error stated above. However, when I paste the video in `JSFiddle` it can be embedded perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vnkLzh9r/3/

The above trick with JSFiddle is something I got from this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55661292/6297856).

As far as I am aware, there are no settings on YouTube to disalow embedding of videos on non-public domains, but yet that seems to be the problem here. Can anyone confirm if that is the underlying issue?

In addition, is there a way for me to embed these videos without having to rely on a public domain?

**Update**

Okay, I have put the iFrame in an Angular project and hosted the project with NG serve. Then I access the page with http://localhost:4200 and the iframe actually works & plays the video. For some reason, when I open the .html file with just the iframe in it, that the video does not want to play? In addition, I have the following debug info of the YT player:

```
{
  "ns": "yt",
  "el": "embedded",
  "cpn": "nVMH8LozAhZ1QLVb",
  "docid": "d6QE4EJrIFc",
  "ver": 2,
  "cmt": "0",
  "ei": "uUlYXfnOCoLj-gbKsYSAAQ",
  "fs": "0",
  "rt": "311.975",
  "euri": "",
  "lact": 1,
  "cl": "263586394",
  "mos": 0,
  "state": "80",
  "volume": 77,
  "c": "WEB_EMBEDDED_PLAYER",
  "cver": "20190816",
  "cplayer": "UNIPLAYER",
  "cbr": "Firefox",
  "cbrver": "68.0",
  "cos": "Windows",
  "cosver": "10.0",
  "hl": "en_US",
  "cr": "NL",
  "len": "254",
  "fexp": "23744176,23751767,23788875,23804281,23818122,23818585,23827085,23829162,23832308,23834462,9449243",
  "size": "315:560",
  "inview": "1",
  "vct": "0.000",
  "vd": "NaN",
  "vpl": "",
  "vbu": "",
  "vpa": "1",
  "vsk": "0",
  "ven": "0",
  "vpr": "1",
  "vrs": "0",
  "vns": "0",
  "vec": "null",
  "vvol": "0.77",
  "creationTime": 313013,
  "totalVideoFrames": 0,
  "droppedVideoFrames": 0,
  "corruptedVideoFrames": 0,
  "debug_error": {
    "errorCode": "auth",
    "errorDetail": "0",
    "errorMessage": "Video unavailable",
    "Ph": "",
    "Uz": "0"
  },
  "relative_loudness": "NaN",
  "user_qual": "hd1080",
  "debug_videoId": "d6QE4EJrIFc",
  "0sz": false,
  "op": "",
  "yof": false,
  "dis": "",
  "gpu": "ANGLE_(NVIDIA_GeForce_GTX_1070_Ti_Direct3D11_vs_5_0_ps_5_0)",
  "cgr": true,
  "debug_playbackQuality": "unknown",
  "debug_date": "Sat Aug 17 2019 20:44:08 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)"
}
```

Comment: Hmm your iframe plays fine on my test domain. Don't know why it doesn't work for you. I don't see any country restrictions.

Comment: @john10 Is your test domain publicly available? or are you (like me) just creating a simple .html file which you open in browser?

Comment: @john10 I just did some further testing... When hosting the file on "localhost" it does work and the video plays. It seems like when I open the HTML file directly it doesn't work...

Comment: @ImJustACowLol I can't find the source, but I do remember a few years ago, a change was made for avoid play YouTube videos (and even Google News API) on .html files. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11305902/4092887) might help you.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave But for some videos it does work... Any idea why? Also, that answer unfortinately didn't help :/

Comment: @ImJustACowLol I know, sorry, I can't remember exactly the reason. Have you tried using this url for get the video's info? `http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=<VIDEO_ID>&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US` and check the differences those videos might have?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Ahh I did not know about that URL. There's too many params to check by hand, but I'll write a script in the evening when I'm back from work to do so. I'll keep you posted :)